Detecting the renaming of a directory containing my log-file
We have a C++ program, that logs its messages into a file. Every once in a while the directory containing this log-file is renamed (or even deleted), and a folder with the same name is created anew.
How would the daemon detect this happening -- so that it can reopen its log? That is, I know, I can do it using inotify (or, more generally, with libevent), but is there, perhaps, anything simpler?
Our Python programs use the logging.handlers.WatchFileHandler() -- is there something like that for C++? I don't need to know about the change immediately -- only when the program has a new message to write out...

I guess, the only portable way is to fstat() the already-opened file-descriptor (once) and stat() the original filename (before each new write) and compare the results.
If the stat() fails, or if the st_dev or st_ino fields filled-out by the two calls aren't the same, reopen the log-file before writing a new log-entry out.
